# excel spreadsheet protection

Tags: excel, numbers, password-protection

I locked spreadsheets in excel (2016) even password-protected them. Just worked fine. 
Then I opened my file with Numbers and everything I protected was visible. How is it possible? What can I do to protect my spreadsheets completely?

Comment: Numbers is really useful when people forget passwords...or produce sheets with errors that need sorting...

Comment: Never worked with numbers so I am spit balling here, but would setting the visibility of the worksheet to xlSheetVeryHidden do the trick?

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick!

Comment: That's still reversible and not complete protection. Encryption is the only actual solution.